# \in misaligned in \sum subscript

Tags: spacing, vertical-alignment, subscripts

The symbol `\in` doesn't seem to fit quite right in the subscript of the sum

```
\sum_{i \in I} \Pr(A_i)
```

For some reason the set-membership symbol seems to be going below the `I` and it looks weird:

[image]

Is there any way I can get the `\in` symbol to look better here? Or is there something I can do to the `I` to make it align properly?

Comment: It's exactly the same as in normal size. If you have `j\in J$, raising the `\in` would look quite bizarre.

Comment: @egreg I was wondering that as I typed the question... but I only noticed it when I saw it in the sum subscript!

Comment: I don't have this problem with your code, so there mmust be something else in your code.

Comment: @Bernard even the online compiler ([Codecogs](https://www.codecogs.com/latex/eqneditor.php)) renders it the same way, [see here](https://latex.codecogs.com/gif.latex?%5Cdpi%7B300%7D%20%5Chuge%20%5Csum_%7Bi%20%5Cin%20I%7D%20%5CPr%28A_i%29). The `\in` symbol is clearly below the bottom of the `I`.

Comment: This might be font dependent. Could you please post a complete MWE beginning at `\documentclass` and ending at `\end{document}`?